# Django URL Dispatcher not matching unicode slug

Tags: django, unicode

I'm currently trying to process a request using unicode-enabled slugs.

i.e., '127.0.0.1:8080/æøå/' works fine for the generic ListView:

```
path('<slug>/', ServiceList.as_view(), name='service-list'),
```

but fails on the DetailView with 0 matches in the SQL query:

```
path('<slug>/', ServiceDetail.as_view(), name='service-detail'),
```

No further errors are given. Am I missing some unicode conversion between the request and the database (SQLite3)?

Comment: I guess the `ServiceList` and `ServiceDetail` dont have the same arguments. This is because if you probably declare the latter with a `pk=None` in arguments. So It wont match the given url. But it will match `127.0.0.1:8080/æøå/:id/`

Answer (score 0):

After add 2nd path, Django are confusing where he should to be go. To resolving it you must have to change the path.
**Each path must have unique url**

Comment: These are two separate examples and are not running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in models.py. It works as expected now.

Before:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Service, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.slug = text.slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
```

After:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = text.slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
    super(Service, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```